# Select Duplicate Records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to retrieve only Duplicated records not unique records.
Suppose I have data which consists of as below

```
Ids Names 
1  A
2  B
1  A
```

I want like output like the following:

```
Sno Id Name 
1  1 A 
2  1 A
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [ID] INT
   ,[name] CHAR(1)
   ,[value] CHAR(2) 
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ID], [name], [value])
VALUES (1, 'A', 'x1')
      ,(2, 'B', 'x2')
      ,(1, 'A', 'x3');

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID], [name]) AS [Count]
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT *
FROM Datasource
WHERE [Count] > 1;
```

[image]

The grouping part is done in the `PARTITION BY` part of the window function. So, basically, we are counting records for each unique `ID` - `name` pairs. Of couse, you are able to add more columns columns here.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id, Names
FROM T
GROUP  BY Id,Name 
HAVING COUNT(*) >1
```

Comment: Thank you. Please suggest what if I have another column which is not forming part of duplicate records. Suppose Name2 column is there. But I want Count(*) should be based on only first two columns.

Comment: MIN(Name2)/MAX(Name2)/FIRST_VALUE or if you want to get all the duplicates, rewrite the query with row_number ()

Comment: While this snippet may answer the question, it's good practice to have some explanatory text saying why this is the answer and assisting the Original Poster to discover this for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

[image]like your request, you need to create a new column [SNo] that is partitioned on the orignal columns (Names, Id). Those with [SNo] >1 are duplicates. To Filter, just get RCount>1.
See a mockup below:

```
 DECLARE @Records TABLE (Id int, Names VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Records
SELECT 1, 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'A'



----To Get Duplicates -----

SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT 
    SNo=ROW_NUMBER()over(PARTITION BY Names,Id order by Id),
    RCount=COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID], Names),
    *
FROM
    @Records
)M
WHERE 
    RCount>1
```